# react auto escapes my html tags

Tags: reactjs, escaping

I'm trying to write a code with react.
When I try to set one of the props with < or > React auto-escapes it.
I've tried using unicode, and risky div, but nothing helped.
React still auto escapes my code.
Can I somehow shut react auto-escaping down?

Comment: I think it's worth providing some more context as there may be a way to avoid doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Dangerously Set innerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to set html, and it won't be escaped:

```
function createMarkup() { return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'}; };
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

Comment: Avoid `#dangerouslySetInnerHTML` where possible https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-danger.md